# Reading date in Accessibility for Android

Tags: android, accessibility

I have two places where date is displayed on the screen in format mm/dd/yyyy.
When I have accessibility talk back feature on in Android it reads both dates in different ways.

For example one date is 11/15/2017 and other is 11/10/2017. Android reads the first one as "November Fifteen Twenty seventeen" and the next one as "Tenth November Twenty Seventeen".

I have checked that device timezone is in US and language is en_US as well. What can be the reason for this?

Comment: One may specify a locale, while the other doesn't.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. At least, yours is reading the day and month right, but different order. Mine isn't even reading date represented as String. It is reading them character-by-character. Tough thing is I've prepended text "As Of" prior to the Date for display, so I convert everything to String to display "As of 11/15/2018", and talk-back is saying " As Of one-one slash one-five slash two-thousand and eighteen". Am like, what the heck??

Comment: @AndroidRocks It's not about the code, you can change the way it reads (characters, word, paragraphs) with a swipe up.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: Talkback has read the Date in a TextView in a wrong way.

I solved it by setting a `contentdescription` on the TextView. So the Screenreader will read the content-description instead of the Text in the TextView.

```
val formatter = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG)
val dateString = formatter.format(yourDate) // dateString = "12. August 2023" (for example)
textview.contentDescription = dateString
```

[Here is android-Dateformat Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/DateFormat)